# Datatable escapeRegex not working. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

jQuery:

```
var select = $('<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple="multiple"><option value=""></option></select>')
    .appendTo($("#filter" + i))
    .on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val !== null) {
            var selectd_value = '';
            for (var j = 0; j <= parseFloat(val.length) - 1; j++) {
                var value = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(val[j]);
                value = value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
                if (j != parseFloat(val.length) - 1) {
                    selectd_value += value + '|';
                } else {
                    selectd_value += value;
                }
            }
            column.search(selectd_value ? '^' + selectd_value + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
        } else {
            show_all(column);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to search Styler King 6 Card Holder (Set of 1, Khaki) but it not returning any result already this is on the table. But still, it not returning How can I resolve this issue? Please help me. Sorry for my weak English.